# MongoError: failed to connect to server - bluemix

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ibm-cloud

I have my NodeJS app which works perfect locally, and now I am trying to upload it in Bluemix.

I am typing in cmd `cf login` and after being successful, I am pushing it with `cf push`. After pushing it, I am trying to run the requests in postman, but I get this error:

> connection error: {MongoError: failed to connect to server [larissa-node.mybluemix.net:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT 169.54.245.69:27017]

I declared the Mongo URL as `mongodb://larissa-node.mybluemix.net` inside a file called `config.js`. I have uploaded my NodeJS project on [GitHub](https://github.com/theo82/capstone-node.js), so you can have a look. Maybe I am missing things.

Comment: make sure your mongodb port 27017 is reachable from the server from where your code is running

Comment: @Astro 4. Hmm. How can I do that? I am confused. 27017 is a default port of mongodb. Do I have to change it?

Comment: if you are on linux, you can use telnet to check if this port is accessible from your app server

Comment: Astro  unfortunately,I am using windows 8.1.

Comment: @Astro 4. Ok I have enabled telnet. Where should I go from there? I have never used it before.

Comment: telnet host port  e.g telnet larissa-node.mybluemix.net 27017

Comment: I get this. Invalid Command. type ?/help for help

Comment: @Astro I type this telnet larissa-node.mybluemix.net 27017

Comment: telnet larissa-node.mybluemix.net 27017

Comment: still nothing:(